# react-select typescript issue - Generic type 'ValueType' requires 2 type argument(s).ts(2314)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-select

I am trying to utilize `react-select` and have the following code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import LanguageChange from '../../../Icons/LanguageChange';
import Select, { ValueType } from 'react-select';

type OptionType = {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  };


export const LanguageSelector = () => {
    const languageOptions: OptionType[] = [
        { value: 'English', label: 'EN' },
        { value: 'German', label: 'DE' },
        { value: 'French', label: 'FR' },
      ];
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<ValueType<OptionType>>(languageOptions[0]);
    const handleChange = (option: ValueType<OptionType>) => {
    setSelectedOption(option);
  };

    return (
        <LanguageChange>
            <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={setSelectedOption}
                options={languageOptions}
            />
        </LanguageChange>
    )
}
```

But I keep getting the following error: (alias) type ValueType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase, IsMulti extends boolean> = IsMulti extends true ? OptionsType : OptionType | null
import ValueType
Generic type 'ValueType' requires 2 type argument(s).ts(2314)

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ValueType` requires two generics: the `OptionType` which you have provided and `IsMulti` which is either `true` or `false`.  `IsMulti` determines whether or not it is an array.  If you have an `OptionType` with `{value: string}`, the `ValueType` if it's a multiple select should be `string[]` whereas for a single select it would be `string`.

In your case you have a single select so you can use `ValueType<OptionType, false>`.  But you can also just use `string` because you already know that the value type of your options is `string` so there is no need to work backwards.

[Source Code](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a577916739f69409af6d502c0a9d24c4843b1c3f/types/react-select/src/types.d.ts#L20)

Comment: @sbuck89 please dont forget to accept the answer

Comment: Is it possible to explain more 
export type ValueType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase, IsMulti extends boolean> = IsMulti extends true
    ? OptionsType<OptionType>
    : OptionType | null;
why = IsMulti extends true  .. its good practice to learn more about TypeScript @linda

Answer (score 0):

Update your onChange function to accept params like this:

```
onChange: (value: ValueType<OptionType, IsMulti>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<OptionType>) => void;
```